How to Reliably Collect Serial Port Data with Flask and React on a Dockerized Raspberry Pi?
I have a Flask server and a React frontend designed to run experiments where data is collected from a serial port. Here’s the setup:
The full application is dockerized and hosted on Raspberry Pi.
React Frontend Features:

Start Timer Button: Begins data collection for an experiment. Triggers backend API endpoint, which starts storing data in a buffer array.
End Timer Button: Stops data collection. Triggers the backend API endpoint which stops storing the data in the buffer and returns that to the frontend.

Requirements:

Only one user at a time.
Only one experiment at a time.
Only one timer should be active on the server.
Delay for the data to show on frontend is accepted.

Problems Faced:

The serial port sometimes disconnects, leading to data loss.
Socket connections occasionally drop, also resulting in data loss.

Proposed Solution:

Use TimescaleDB to store the collected data.
Forward the stored data from TimescaleDB to the frontend.

Question:

What’s the best way to address these issues and improve the overall setup?
Should the serial port connection be established every time the timer starts, or should it remain persistent?


Depending on the environment in which the device is placed and operated, it may be possible that a spike in electro static discharge may cause the USB device to temporarily not be recognized. In Windows, there is a way to use devcon.exe to soft-disconnect the USB device and make it recognized again. You may want to search for a similar function in Unix.
